# How to do a pivot with the header on each line?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, mssql-jdbc

I am converting from a old system, the only way to get the data out of the old system is using its internal export feature. This produces a file with a new line for each header (almost like XML). I need to find a way to use SQL to transform this data into a MSSQL database. Below is an example of how the data looks.

Number    15;123
 
Name    John    Doe
Phone    5555551234
Note    
Email    
Password   1234    5432    5672    2212
END    
Number    15;124
 
Name    Foo    Bar
Phone    5555559876
Note    Crazy man
Email    Email@server.domain
Password    0    0    0    0
END 
(the data repeats in this format)

The data in the lines are separated by a tab
The columns are each line, the column name is the first word, so the first line's column name would be "Number", the second "Name" and so on. 

What would be the best way to get the data into a MSSQL database? I have thought of using a PIVOT but the header would be in every other line.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: i think it is easy to convert this data to excel and use that macro which convert repeated blocks data to normal data then it will be easy to convert this excel to sql

Answer (score 0):

You can run a regex on the file first.
**(I'm sorry for my poor regex skills!)**

Something like:(*Tested on Notepad++*)

Find:

```
^.[^\s]+\s(.*)\r\n.[^\s]+\s(.*)\r\n.[^\s]+\s(.*)\r\n.[^\s]+\s(.*)\r\n.[^\s]+\s(.*)\r\n.[^\s]+\s(.*)\r\n[E][N][D]
```

Replace With:

```
"\1";"\2";"\3";"\4";"\5";"\6"
```

Should be ready to load to SQL with SSIS or even BCP.